# How do you configure Password Recovery control in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a password recovery control that is set up to ask the user their security question.  I have configured the from email and subject, but I am receiving a runtime error stating SMTP host is not specified.

Can someone tell me where I need to set the host?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a system.net section to your web.config with the following:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="yourmailserveraddress"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: I found it after changing my Google search (removing the space between password and recovery)